# Oracle Date datatype, transformed to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TMZ' through SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I have an application that uploads to an Oracle Data datatype column via:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2012-10-09 1:10:21 CST','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR')
```

I now need to pull the following format and timezone from this Data column:
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS CDT'

Note: that the date is uploaded in CST but needs to be returned in CDT.

I have Google'd but have only found following for Date datatypes:

```
SELECT dateColumn From dateTable;
09-NOV-12

SELECT TO_CHAR(dateColumn,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') From dateTable;
2012-10-09 1:10:21
```

I have tried the following also:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(dateColumn,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS CDT')
data format not recognized

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(CRTE_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM')
09-NOV-12 1:10:21 AM +01:00
don't understand why this does not come back as YYYY-MM-DD?
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion in your question:

- a `Date` datatype doesn't save the time zone component. This piece of information is truncated and lost forever when you insert a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` into a `Date`.
- When you want to display a date, either on screen or to send it to another system via a character API (XML, file...), you use the [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#i1009324) function. In Oracle, **a `Date` has no format**: it is a point in time.
- Reciprocally, you would use [`TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions214.htm#i999847) to convert a `VARCHAR2` to a `TIMESTAMP`, but this won't convert a `Date` to a `TIMESTAMP`.
- You use `FROM_TZ` to add the time zone information to a `TIMESTAMP` (or a `Date`).
- In Oracle, `CST` is a time zone but `CDT` is not. `CDT` is a daylight saving information.
- To complicate things further, `CST/CDT` (`-05:00`) and `CST/CST` (`-06:00`) will have different values obviously, but the time zone `CST` will inherit the daylight saving information depending upon the date by default.

So your conversion may not be as simple as it looks.

Assuming that you want to convert a `Date` `d` that you know is valid at time zone `CST/CST` to the equivalent at time zone `CST/CDT`, you would use:

```
SQL> SELECT from_tz(d, '-06:00') initial_ts,
  2         from_tz(d, '-06:00') at time zone ('-05:00') converted_ts
  3    FROM (SELECT cast(to_date('2012-10-09 01:10:21',
  4                              'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as timestamp) d
  5            FROM dual);

INITIAL_TS                      CONVERTED_TS
------------------------------- -------------------------------
09/10/12 01:10:21,000000 -06:00 09/10/12 02:10:21,000000 -05:00
```

My default timestamp format has been used here. I can specify a format explicitely:

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(from_tz(d, '-06:00'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR') initial_ts,
  2         to_char(from_tz(d, '-06:00') at time zone ('-05:00'),
  3                 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR') converted_ts
  4    FROM (SELECT cast(to_date('2012-10-09 01:10:21',
  5                              'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as timestamp) d
  6            FROM dual);

INITIAL_TS                      CONVERTED_TS
------------------------------- -------------------------------
2012-10-09 01:10:21 -06:00      2012-10-09 02:10:21 -05:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your post Vincent. It is exactly what I was looking for :) My SQL looks like the following now encase it helps anyone else:

    SELECT
        to_char(
            (
                FROM_TZ(
                    CAST(dateColumn AS TIMESTAMP), '-06:00'
                )
                AT TIME ZONE '-05:00'
            )
            ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR'
        )
    FROM 
        dateTable;

One last question, is it possible to convert the "-06:00" to CDT at all?

Comment: For the  '-05:00' -> 'CDT', I was able to wrap the to_char in a replace(). Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: Not really, `CDT` is not the time zone: you will have CDT in summer and CST in winter, always. For example, this produces an error: `SELECT to_timestamp_tz('2013-01-01 CST CDT', 'yyyy-mm-dd TZR TZD') FROM dual`, but if you replace january by june it works OK. So you can't really convert a `CST/CST` to a `CST/CDT` because a given date can't be both (except during the transition hour before winter, e.g. `2013-11-03 01:00:00`)

Comment: Yes, the time changes from CST to CDT during the year, but CST always remains UTC -6 and CDT always remains UTC -5. So if an application always inputs time as CST (no matter when inputted throughout the year), the time can then be associated with UTC -6 and UTC -5 applied to it, giving CDT but never mentioning CST or CDT as both are not supported within oracle.

Comment: You are a beautiful man, Vincent.  One thing -- I was using this in Netsuite, which uses oracle (or its syntax) at the backend, and the from_tz didn't work on a date.  It worked after casting to timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

to convert a TimestampTZ in oracle, you do

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2012-10-09 1:10:21 CST','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') 
  at time zone 'region'
```

see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG264

and here  for regions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#NLSPG0141

eg:

```
SQL> select a, sys_extract_utc(a), a at time zone '-05:00' from (select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2013-04-09 1:10:21 CST','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') a from dual);

A
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(A)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AATTIMEZONE'-05:00'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
09-APR-13 01.10.21.000000000 CST
09-APR-13 06.10.21.000000000
09-APR-13 01.10.21.000000000 -05:00


SQL> select a, sys_extract_utc(a), a at time zone '-05:00' from (select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2013-03-09 1:10:21 CST','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') a from dual);

A
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(A)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AATTIMEZONE'-05:00'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
09-MAR-13 01.10.21.000000000 CST
09-MAR-13 07.10.21.000000000
09-MAR-13 02.10.21.000000000 -05:00

SQL> select a, sys_extract_utc(a), a at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles' from (select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2013-04-09 1:10:21 CST','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') a from dual);

A
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(A)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AATTIMEZONE'AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
09-APR-13 01.10.21.000000000 CST
09-APR-13 06.10.21.000000000
08-APR-13 23.10.21.000000000 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

Comment: Thank you for your post DazzaL, although not mentioned in you post, the links you gave put me on the path of FROM_TZ and CAST, and I was close to the answer before Vincent provided full solution. Please view Vincent's post for full solution if you are interested in what I was looking for exactly. Thank you again, I voted you up btw ;)