# How to convert oracle date format to IST format?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In my Oracle table the the date format is like this 03-AUG-2018.

When i query this table i want the output format is like this ("2018-08-03T18:11:42.413+0530").

This my query which i tried to convert.

```
SELECT app_id,
       TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(created_on,'DD-MM-YYYYHH:MI:SSTZH:TZM'),
       TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(request_date,'DD-MM-YYYYHH:MI:SSTZH:TZM') 
FROM   NUCPRODLOSSTG.LOS_APP_APPLICATIONS
 where created_on between '01-AUG-2018' and '31-AUG-2018' 
and app_id in (123,321,124);
```

Comment: And what happens when you run that query???

Comment: I'm getting the date format like this "17-AUG-03 11.37.00.000000000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA"

Comment: What is the data type of column `created_on` and `request_date`?

Comment: you might want to have a look at the standard docs - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Date datatype, transformed to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TMZ' through SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833030/oracle-date-datatype-transformed-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hh24miss-tmz-through-sql)