# varchar2 string to Date format

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to convert the below string value to TO_DATE but oracle is not 
recognizing the date format.  Where am I going wrong.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('Wed Oct 10 23:50:00 2018 UTC','Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY TZR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') 
FROM dual;
```

ERROR at line 1:

> ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833030/oracle-date-datatype-transformed-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hh24miss-tmz-through-sql#15834821

Comment: Are the string values always UTC? If so you could just ignore that part by treating it as a literal in the format mask.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Wed Oct 10 23:50:00 2018 UTC','DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY TZR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American') 
FROM dual;
```

---

[TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) function returns DATE datatype, which does not support timezones. You are using `TZR` format specifier in your query (time zone region), and this generates the error because DATE does not support this.

---

[This documentation - Time Zones](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1841) shows which datatypes supports timezones, and states that only `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` do. So you must convert to one of this datatype instead of converting to DATE.
[TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm) function converts a literal to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` datatype.

Comment: Thanks. That works.  How do I get  time difference in HH:MI:SS format for 2 dates in the above format :  for example  'Wed Oct 10 23:50:00 2018 UTC'   -   'Wed Oct 07 23:50:00 2018 UTC'

Comment: @user3444050 - convert them both to timestamp with time zone as shown, and then either subtract them (to get an interval), or cast to dates if they're always in the same TZ and subtract those (to get a number of days). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45601629/266304) has some pointers to get to the difference in your desired format, whichever way you do the subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

If (and I realise it's a big 'if') the string values always contain UTC and not any other time zone values, then you could just treat that as a [character literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A). You would do that by changing your format model from `TZR`, which isn't recognised by `to_date()`, to `"UTC"` - including the double quotes:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('Wed Oct 10 23:50:00 2018 UTC',
  'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY "UTC"',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') 
FROM dual;

TO_DATE('WEDOCT1023
-------------------
2018-10-10 23:50:00
```

Of course, as that is a plain date it still has no time zone information, but if you want to retain that then you need a timestamp with [local] time zone data type anyway.